# What is co-relation between libjna-jni, libjna-java libraries and Java

Tags: java, cassandra

I want to know more about libjna-jni and libjna-java libraries. What is the relationship between Java and these libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[libjna-jni](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libjna-jni) contains native libraries (os/architecture dependent) for [JNA (Java Native Access) library](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) that allows access to native libraries without creating explicit JNI wrapper. [libjna-java](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/libjna-java) contains Java part of this library.